# PrimeFaces 3.4 Charts datatipFormat

Tags: java, charts, primefaces

today I wanted to try the new PrimeFaces release 3.4.RC1.
For charts there is a new attribute called datatipFormat.

I want to show only the value (y-axis) in a line chart as datatip.
Like this:

```
<p:lineChart value="#{...}" datatipFormat="y-value"/>
```

What do I have to do to show only this? 
I could not find an example with a template String.

Best Regards
Veote

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Primefaces uses a jqPlot Library for Charts. There I found the following entry:

[Highlighter.formatString](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-highlighter-js.html)

I tried (example from Primefaces Showcase):

```
   <p:lineChart  id="basic" value="#{userBean.categoryModel}" legendPosition="ne" 
   datatipFormat="#{userBean.datatipFormat}"  title="Basic Bar Chart" min="0"
    max="200" style="height:300px"/>
```

UserBean

```
public String getDatatipFormat(){
   return "<span style=\"display:none;\">%s</span><span>%s</span>";
}
```

and with this little trick is only y-axis displays.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `extender` property of all PrimeFaces chart tags to override default plot options. Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function customExtender() {
    this.cfg.highlighter = {
      useAxesFormatters: false,
      tooltipAxes: 'y'
    }
  }
</script>
...
<p:lineChart extender="customExtender" value="..." />
```

Other available jqplot options can be found here: http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotOptions-txt.html but please note that the document says it is out of date.

Answer (score 4):

datatipFormat uses sprintf to format the string for the tooltip, so you can print only the second parameter (y-axis):

```
<p:lineChart value="#{...}" datatipFormat="%2$d"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Tip for BarChartModel():

```
public String getDatatipFormatX() {
    return "<font size=4 color=blue><span style=\"display:none;\">%s</span><span>%s</span></font>";
}
```

Tip for HorizontalBarChartModel():

```
public String getDatatipFormatY() {
    return "<font size=4 color=blue><span>%s</span><span style=\"display:none;\">%s</span></font>";
}
```

Examples of usage:

```
private void MyCharts(){

//get data (from database, for example) to be displayed

myBarChartModel = new BarChartModel();
myHorizontalBarChartModel = new HorizontalBarChartModel();

ChartSeries verticalSeries = new ChartSeries("verticalSeries");
ChartSeries horizontalSeries = new ChartSeries("horizontalSeries");

myBarChartModel.addSeries(verticalSeries);
myHorizontalBarChartModel.addSeries(horizontalSeries);

myBarChartModel.setDatatipFormat(getDatatipFormatX());
myHorizontalBarChartModel.setDatatipFormat(getDatatipFormatY());
//other chart settings...

}
```

Then, in JSF page:

```
<p:chart type="bar" model="#{chartBean.myBarChartModel}" />
<p:chart type="bar" model="#{chartBean.myHorizontalBarChartModel}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can show only the first 0 characters of the x value (%.0s), what means to hide it. Behind it you can do what you want with the y value in sprintf format.

```
yourBarChartModel.setDatatipFormat("%.0s%s");
```