# primefaces barchart : displaying data point on bar

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

how can I display data point on bar in barchart?

I don't want to use datatip or tooltip which will highlight data points only when they are moused over.

I want to display the data point always on the bar.

is there any right way to get it?

thanks.

I want exactly like this

[image: DataPoint on Bar]

following is my code

```
<p:barChart id="barChartId" value="#{myBean.myModel}"             
        orientation="horizontal"             
        stacked="true" extender="ext" animate="true" shadow="false" />              
<h:outputScript>         
  function ext() {  
    this.cfg.highlighter = {
             useAxesFormatters: false,
             tooltipAxes: 'x'   
    };      
    this.cfg.legend = {
            show: true,
            location: 'ne',
            placement: 'outside'
    }; 
    this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
            pointLabels : { show: true },
    };              
  }        
</h:outputScript>
```

here, highlighter and legend are working fine but point labels are not displaying on bar

Comment: see :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050008/primefaces-3-4-charts-datatipformat

Comment: @NickHol:But I want  data Value on the bar  not in a toolTip

Comment: You can just change the css using that so that it will always show.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if it will work...

Use the `extender` of the `<p:barChart` , like this:

```
<p:barChart value="#{myBean.myModel}" widgetVar="myBarChart" extender="my_ext"/>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function my_ext() {
        this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            pointLabels: {show: true}
        };
        this.cfg.stackSeries: true;
    }
</script>
```

or this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function my_ext() {
        this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
            pointLabels: {show: true}
        };
        this.cfg.stackSeries: true;
    }
</script>
```

---

Also take a look at the jqplot examples : [Bar charts](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what is typo

Comment: typo = a typographical error , I accidently typed wrong characters , try the code now...

Comment: :I am not getting by using this.My graph is stacked. Is there Any jqPlot jar required for this?

Comment: To resolve this I added one jar file for pointLables "jqplot.pointLabels.min.js" and now it working fine with your answer. Any way your answer helped me. Thank you

Comment: Cool , that js was in that link I posted in my answer... (although I wasn't aware that it was needed)

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone doesn't crawl through the comments of the marked answer, as I didn't do in the first place.

The problem basically is not the configuration of the `pointLabels`element, but rather that primefaces (as of 4.0) in its original state does not ship with the needed plugin of jqPlot included.

Therefore actually the solution is to make the needed plugin `jqplot.pointLabels.min.js` available. From a ticket in the bug tracker (http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=5378) I extracted, that primefaces uses jqPlot version 1.0.8.

- download jqplot 1.0.8 from https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/downloads/
- add the plugin to your project (e.g. `src/main/webapp/resources/jqplot-plugins`)
- add the plugin as script to your page (`<h:outputScript  library="jqplot-plugins" name="jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"  />`)