# how to show values on barChart in primefaces with out mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I want to show fixed values on the barChart in primefaces , so i can show all values of the graphe in same time . is there an option in barchart that allow that ?? or i need use something else ??

```
<p:barChart id="horizontal" value="#{gestionduplanning.categoryModel}" legendPosition="se" style="height:300px"  
            title="Horizontal Bar Chart" orientation="horizontal" min="0" max="200" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Show all values in same time"?

Comment: Already answered in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250638/primefaces-barchart-displaying-data-point-on-bar