# Primefaces 5.2 : customize charts datatip

Tags: jsf, primefaces, charts, jqplot, datatip

I want to customize the datatip in Primefaces 5.2 charts.
So it means, that I want to change the datatipFormat and the content on it.

It tried this:

--- XHTML ---

```
<p:chart type="line" 
         model="#{lineChartController.lineModel}"
         title="#{lineChartController.lineModel.title}"
         showDatatip="#{lineChartController.lineModel.showDatatip}"
         datatipFormat="#{lineChartController.datatipFormat}"
         ... />
```

--- Java ---

```
public String getDatatipFormat()
{
    return "<span style=\"display:none;\">%s</span><span>%s</span>";
}
```

isShowDatatip() returns true.

The customized datatipFormat doesn't seem to work, moreover I don't know how to put the data I want on the %s.

To resume:

- I have this [Simple Primefaces 5.2 chart datatip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOBve.png)
- I want this [Customized chart datatip from D3.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2BLC.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050008/primefaces-3-4-charts-datatipformat), it leads me to the wrong direction.

I put  my Java code on the LineChartController and my showDatatip leads to a LineChartModel ... which contains a setDatatipFormat(String) method.

So I use it:

```
LineChartModel lineModel = new LineChartModel();
...
lineModel.setDatatipFormat("<table><thead><tr><th>Date</th></tr></thead><tbody><td>%s</td><td>%s EUR</td></tbody></table>");
```

And I still don't know how to put the data I want in the %s.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<p:overlayPanel>` for this

```
    <p:overlayPanel id="myPanel" for="myLbl" showEvent="mouseover" hideEvent="mouseout">
           <p:panelGrid columns="2">  
                <f:facet name="header">#{controller. getDate()}</f:facet>                   
                 <h:outputLabel value="#{controller.dataItem.Col1}" />             
                 <h:outputLabel value="#{controller.dataItem.Col2}" />    

           </p:panelGrid>  
  </p:overlayPanel>
```

and bind this overlay onn mousehover of desired point in your chart alrernatively you can call overlay from javascript as well catch the mousehover event of chart.

Comment: I tried your code, itis nice but, do you know how to retrieve information from the chart (x and y coordinates for instance) ? Because otherwise the datas are static.