# Primefaces 6.2 BarChart DatatipFormat

Tags: charts, primefaces, bar-chart, jsf-2.2

I am currently working with Primefaces 6.2 and JSF 2.2 and I am trying to build a bar chart. The chart itself is being rendered properly, but right now, the datatip of every value is the "y" value concatenated with the "x" value:
`barModel.setDatatipFormat("%d - %.2f");`
Ex:
'1 - 132.70',
'2 - 96.00',
'3 - 103.25'
....

What I need is to display only the second value:
'132.70',
'96.00',
'103.25'
....

But every time I try to make something different like `barModel.setDatatipFormat("%.2f");`, only the first value is formatted and shown.

Is there a way to, for instance, ignore this first value? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I tryed to do the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050008/primefaces-3-4-charts-datatipformat) question, but there is no `<p:lineChart.../>` tag in Primefaces 6.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parameter index in your format String, as it's a classical format supported by `String.format` or `System.out.printf`. Parameter index starts at `1` not `0`.

In your case, just try this `"%2$.2f"`.

See also : http://devdocs.io/openjdk~8/java/util/formatter